# Young`s double slits experiment

Tags: visible-light, waves, double-slit-experiment, interference

[image]

At the constructive points on the screen, their constructive amplitudes are equal. So these points must be equally bright, but they are not! 
Why does this phenomena happen?

NB: I have taken this pic from a video of khan academy where the mentioned term is not clearly explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of Huygens secondary wavelets instead of the amplitude of a wavelet being the same in all directions the amplitude is proportional to $1+\cos \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the forward direction and the direction under consideration.
So the amplitude of the wavelet in the forward direction is twice that of the amplitude at right angles $(\theta = \frac \pi 2 ^{\rm c})$ to the forward direction.

Comment: Amplitude of a secondary wavelet changes, as its angle from reference line increases...Before your answer I didn't know that......I think I have got my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this experiment, one single photon is shot at a time. The photon travels as a wave, and travels through both slits and interferes with itself.

The brighter parts are because of constructive interference.

The darker parts because of destructive interference.

Now you are asking why the pattern gets less and less brighter as you go away from the center.

You have to use math to get the wavefunction describing the probability distribution of the particles as per QM.

Now the source of the waves is in the center, and waves are radially going out from there in your picture.

Now in the center, the constructive interference is the strongest, because both parts of the wave reach each other untouched (least touched).
So in the middle, the waves interfere with each other without before  destructively interfering with each other.

You can get the strongest constructive interference, if neither parts of the wave have before destructively interfered with another part of the wave. That happens near the center line, where the emission happened. Both waves travel without (or the least) interfering with another part of the wave.

As you go away from the center, waves are interfering destructively, and the chances and effects of constructive interference are less and less because the source of the two parts of the wave are farther away and waves by the time they get there have already destructively interfered so the change and effect of constructive interference is little.

Of course as you go away from the center, you can say that because of the destructive interference, the amplitude decreases.

Comment: Are the amplitudes of the 2 waves are dropping? Obviously they are not either at the centre bright point or far bright point from the centre.Am I right? If I am , the constructive amplitude at every bright point must be equal...We know intensity is proportion to the square of amplitude. Then at the brightness of the const. points have to be same.....Is there anything wrong in my logic?

Comment: The reason the brightness of those pattern areas decreases is because the amplitude of the waves decreases away from the center line. Now these lower amplitude wave parts will still create constructive interference, but their amplitude is lower. The constructive interference is the highest in the center line because those wave parts that create the center pattern area have the highest amplitude.

Comment: But there is another reason. You could say that in the center, and close to the center, the waves that interfere constructively, those wave parts have not previously interfered destructively with other wave parts. As you go away from the center, the wave parts there have already destructively interfered with other parts of the wave. Destructive interference will not completely destroy a wave, it will just lower the amplitude. The more destructive interference for a wave, the lower the amplitude. The farther it goes from the center, the more destructive interference and lower amplitude.

Answer (score 0):

The brightness of the peaks is reduced as you move away from the center because of: 1) the fact that the amplitude of each wave is greater near the axis of the system because the slits have finite width; 2) the fact that the amplitude drops as $1/r $ (the intensity drops as $1/r^2$) even if the slit width were infinitely small, where $r$ is the distance from the slit; and 3) the fact that the source is only approximately a point source and only approximately monochromatic & coherent.